# How to convert SparseVector to MatrixEntry

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark

this is my SparseVector:

```
mx.foreach(println)

SparseVector((0,1.0), (1,0.0), (2,0.0), (3,0.0), (4,0.0), (5,0.0), (6,0.0), (7,0.0), (8,0.0), (9,0.0), (10,0.0), (11,0.0), (12,0.0))
SparseVector((0,0.0), (1,1.0), (2,0.0), (3,0.0), (4,0.0), (5,0.0), (6,0.0), (7,0.0), (8,0.0), (9,0.0), (10,0.0), (11,0.0), (12,0.0))
SparseVector((0,0.0), (1,0.0), (2,1.0), (3,0.0), (4,0.0), (5,0.0), (6,0.0), (7,0.0), (8,0.0), (9,0.0), (10,0.0), (11,0.0), (12,0.0))
SparseVector((0,0.0), (1,0.0), (2,0.0), (3,1.0), (4,0.0), (5,0.0), (6,0.0), (7,0.0), (8,0.0), (9,0.0), (10,0.0), (11,0.0), (12,0.0))
```

i want convert to MatrixEntry?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: given that `mx`'s type is `RDD[SparseVector[Double]]`:

```
val matrixEntries: RDD[MatrixEntry] = mx.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
  case (vector, i) => vector.toArray.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (v, j) => MatrixEntry(i, j, v)
  }
}
```

Comment: mx type is RDD[SparseVector[Double]]

Comment: Oh, sorry - right, that's SparseVector's toString that adds those indices  - answer fixed accordingly.

Comment: i can't get the SparseVector((0,1.0), (1,0.0), (2,0.0), (3,0.0)) 0,1,2 and 3 because the type is SparseVector[Double]

Comment: I don't understand your comment - the code above works for `mx` of type `RDD[SparseVector[Double]]` - it was changed, it now adds indices for both the rows and the columns.